# Haskell Space Overflow

Tags: haskell, ghc

I've compiled this program and am trying to run it.

```
import Data.List
import Data.Ord
import qualified Data.MemoCombinators as Memo

collatzLength :: Int -> Int
collatzLength = Memo.arrayRange (1, 1000000) collatzLength'
  where
    collatzLength' 1 = 1
    collatzLength' n | odd n  = 1 + collatzLength (3 * n + 1)
                     | even n = 1 + collatzLength (n `quot` 2)

main = print $ maximumBy (comparing fst) $ [(collatzLength n, n) | n <- [1..1000000]]
```

I'm getting the following from GHC

```
Stack space overflow: current size 8388608 bytes.
Use `+RTS -Ksize -RTS' to increase it.
```

I assume this is one of the "space overflow" things I've been hearing about. (I'm pretty new to Haskell.) How do I fix it? Do I have to rewrite collatzLength to be tail recursive?

Comment: How are running this?  It works for me when compiled with `ghc -O`, using ghc-7.0.4.

Comment: @yairchu: I disagree; none of the answers are really great but Henning's is accurate.  The code as given has different behavior depending on the bit size; the stack overflow appears with 32-bit ints (either from 32-bit ghc or explicitly using `Int32`).

Comment: @John L: got it, I misunderstood. In that case, hammar's answer is the comprehensive one and should be marked.

Comment: Which optimizations, specifically, are happening with -O or -O2 that magically solve this problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As the author of the code in question, I am now slightly embarrassed because it has not one but *two* possible stack overflow bugs.

1. It uses `Int`. On a 32-bit system this will overflow, as the Collatz sequence can go quite a bit higher than the starting number. This overflow can cause infinite recursion as the function jumps back and forth between negative and positive values.

   In the case of numbers between one and a million, the worst starting point is 704511, which goes as high as 56,991,483,520 before coming back down towards 1. This is well outside the 32-bit range.
2. It uses `maximumBy`. This function is not strict, so it will cause a stack overflow when used on long lists. One million elements is more than enough for this to happen with the default stack size. It still works with optimizations enabled, though, due to the strictness analysis performed by GHC.

   The solution is to use a strict version. Since none is available in the standard libraries, we can use the strict left fold ourselves.

Here is an updated version which should (hopefully) be stack overflow-free, even without optimizations.

```
import Data.List
import Data.Ord
import qualified Data.MemoCombinators as Memo

collatzLength :: Integer -> Integer
collatzLength = Memo.arrayRange (1,1000000) collatzLength'
  where
    collatzLength' 1 = 1
    collatzLength' n | odd n  = 1 + collatzLength (3 * n + 1)
                     | even n = 1 + collatzLength (n `quot` 2)

main = print $ foldl1' max $ [(collatzLength n, n) | n <- [1..1000000]]
```

Comment: Btw, in this case `max` would work just as well as `(maxBy fst)`.

Comment: @yairchu: You're absolutely right. It's really not my day, is it? :)

Comment: How to make ```collatzLength``` as a function takes two arguments that we can replace the value of 1000000 with something else ?

Answer (score 7):

Here's a shorter program that fails in the same way:

```
main = print (maximum [0..1000000])
```

Yep.

```
$ ghc --make harmless.hs && ./harmless
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( harmless.hs, harmless.o )
Linking harmless ...
Stack space overflow: current size 8388608 bytes.
Use `+RTS -Ksize -RTS' to increase it.
```

With `-O2` it works. What do I make of it? I don't know :( These space mysteries are a serious gotcha.

**Edit:**

Thx to hammar for pointing out the culprit.

Changing your program to use

```
maximum' = foldl1' max
```

Makes it work without `-O2`. The implementation of `Prelude`'s `maximum` is lazy and so doesn't quite work for long lists without compiler magic dust.

Comment: Indeed, `maximum` and `maximumBy` are both non-strict, so without the strictness analysis this will cause stack overflows. Good catch! I got a manual version using the strict `foldl1'` to work without optimizations.

Comment: @hammar, that makes sense. Write it up as an answer!

Answer (score 6):

I think it's most likely that you're hitting integer overflow with some of the Collatz sequences, and then ending up in an "artificial" cycle that contains overflows but never hits 1. That would produce an infinite recursion.

Remember that some Collatz sequences get very much larger than their starting number before they finally (?) end up at 1.

Try to see if it fixes your problem to use `Integer` instead of `Int`.

Comment: This isn't it (according to theory and a test).  There's just no tail recursion and no intelligent optimization so he's making a really deep stack.

Comment: @Thomas, That was my first guess too, but [according to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture#Examples), there's no starting point less than a billion that requires more than 1000 steps to reach 1. And a recursion depth of 1000 shouldn't produce an 8 megabyte stack even with the least optimized execution strategy. (Is it the final million-element list comprehension that fails to stay in constant space without optimization?)

Comment: Hummm, not sure then.  I read the answer swapped (that's FYI if you saw my other comment before I deleted it), so I see the maximum here is a depth of 525.  Still, the swap is growing over 70M before completion if you don't use optimization.

Comment: This seems to be correct. Changing `Int` (64-bit on my system) to `Int32`, I can reproduce the stack overflow. A small test program reveals that the Collatz sequence for 704511 goes as high as 56991483520, which is well out of 32-bit range.

Comment: It works fine when compiling with `-O2`, so probably not an infinite loop.

Comment: @hammer On my 64bit machine even `Int` will result in a stack space overflow.  They don't for you? Did you use the same optimization flags?  EDIT: ahh, but even with optimization it overflows.  I see.

Comment: @Thomas: I though I had tried that. Seems I had not. Testing some more I find that the 64-bit version fails without `-O2`. The 32-bit version always fails. So both answers may be right. This is using GHC 7.0.2.

Answer (score 4):

Use the optimizer (via the `-O2` flag) any time you are concerned about performance.  GHC's optimizations are hugely important not just to run time but to stack use.  I've tested this with GHC 7.2 and optimization takes care of your issue.

EDIT: In addtion, if you're on a 32 bit machine be sure to use `Int64` or `Word64`.  You'll overflow the size of a 32 bit int and cause non-termination otherwise  (thanks to Henning for this, upvote his answer).

Comment: But how would even a completely naive reduction strategy lead to an overflow here? Is there something inside the memoizer that requires optimization to work?

Comment: I had used the -O2 flag. I should've specified that in my post. It turns out, I needed to use the "Integer" type. I forgot that even though my system is 64-bit, the operating system I'm currently on is 32-bit.